# A median that doesn't divide the sum of two elements in cases when there is an even number of elements

Tags: python, pandas, median

Tried searching, it did not turn up anything relevant. Let's say we have a series with even number of numbers, and we want to calculate its median:

```
pd.Series([4, 6, 8, 10]).median()
```

Since we have an even number of elements, there's no element that is exactly in the middle, so instead the method performs the calculation: (6 + 8) / 2 = 7. However, for my purposes it is very important that the median is a number that already exists in the Series, it can't be something calculated from scratch. So I'd rather pick either 6 or 8 than use 7.

One of the possible solutions is to detect the fact that there is an even number of elements and, in such cases, add another element that is guaranteed to be the largest or the smallest, and then just delete it after I get the median. But this solution seems rather clumsy even for a case with one Series. And if we're dealing with a SeriesGroupBy object instead, where such median has to be calculated for each group separately, I can't even begin to imagine how to implement that.

It looks like there's no parameter in the `median()` method that makes it select one of the two nearest elements instead of dividing, and I can't find any alternative to `median()` method that can do that either. Is implementing my own median function my only choice?

Comment: Do you have to use pandas?

Comment: I couldn't find another way. But defining a function is very easy.

Comment: Without pandas it's just `sorted(l)[len(l)//2]`

Comment: @Barmar Actually, it's `sorted(l)[ceil(len(l)/2)]`. If you use `sorted(l)[len(l)//2]`, when the number of elements in the list is odd, it will return an inaccurate median.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using median you should probably use the quantile option (default is median, the 0.5 quantile), and set interpolation to higher, lower, or nearest.

E.g.

```py
>>> pd.Series([4, 6, 8, 10]).quantile(q=0.5, interpolation='nearest')
8
>>> pd.Series([4, 6, 8, 10]).quantile(q=0.5, interpolation='higher')
8
>>> pd.Series([4, 6, 8, 10]).quantile(q=0.5, interpolation='lower')
6
```

Comment: @UchuuStranger Whoops, glad you (and Trenton) caught the return value typo. FYI, looks like the nearest picks the upper value when there's a tie as in your case of 0.5 quantile and even number of indices but if you go slightly over or under the 0.5 quantile then nearest unambiguously determines the closest fraction as noted in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use pandas, you can do it by simply sorting the list and then getting the middle element. Use integer division to ensure that you get an actual index without a fraction.

```
def list_median(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return None # or maybe raise an error
    return sorted(l)[(len(l) - 1) // 2]
```

Examples:

If the list length is `7` (odd), the media is index 3, and `(len(l) - 1) // 2) == 3`.

If the list length is `8` (even), the median is between indexes 3 and 4, and `(len(l) - 1) // 2) == 3`, which is the first of those two indexes.

Comment: I do need to use pandas, because I need to apply this function to the SeriesGroupBy object. Tried to use your version through _apply()_ method. It works, but only on sub-series that don't have any missing values, your function doesn't account for them. _quantile()_ method does, so that's what I'm going to use. Thank you though.